# Регулярные выражения, парсинг заголовков ссылок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как парсю, но нужны только заголовки:

```
preg_match( '/<ul class="class1 (statichnii)"><li class="class2 (statichnii)">(.*?)<\/ul><\/li>/is' , $text , $links );
echo $links[0];
```

Исходные данные:

```
<ul class="class1 (statichnii)">
 <li class="class2 (statichnii)"><a href="http://random" class="random">Darth Vader</a></li>
 <li class="class2 (statichnii)"><a href="http://random" class="random">Anakin Skywalker</a></li>
</ul>
```

Требуется вытащить: Darth Vader, Anakin Skywalker.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="https://www.google.ru/?q=Darth+Vader">Darth Vader</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://www.google.ru/?q=Anakin+Skywalker">Anakin Skywalker</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ничего что исходные данные под твою регулярку не сматчатся?

Answer (score 2):

```
$html = '<ul class="class1 (statichnii)">
<li class="class2 (statichnii)"><a href="http://random" class="random">Darth Vader</a></li>
<li class="class2 (statichnii)"><a href="http://random" class="random">Anakin Skywalker</a></li>
</ul>';   

$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item)
{
    echo $item->nodeValue , "\n";
}
```

Смотрите [результат](http://ideone.com/KV5mDI).

В PHP существуют [нативные средства](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) для работы с DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Вот регулярка для получения нужных данных из ссылок

```
/<a.*?>\s*([^<\s](?:[^<]*[^<\s])*)\s*</i
```

хотя ответ от @romeo через DOM более правильный.

P.S. Пример работы регулярки https://regex101.com/r/lK3zF6/1

Comment: Да, при использовании UTF-8 к модификатору `i` следует добавить модификатор `u`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, этот вариант мне больше подходит. Сейчас пойду тестить.

Comment: Как учесть, чтобы сбор происходил только из <ul class="class1 (statichnii)">?

`preg_match( '/<ul class="class1 (statichnii)"><li class="class2 (statichnii)"><a.*?>\s*([^<\s](?:[^<]*[^<\s])*)\s*</i<\/ul><\/li>/is' , $text , $links );`

Comment: @user5419467, для этого вам нужно другим регулярным выражением выделить блок `<ul class="class1 (statichnii)">...</ul>` из основного текста и к нему применить регулярку из ответа, либо воспользоваться ответом от **romeo** и через DOM достать нужные элементы.